# Semantic-Ui-React Popup with Moment does not work

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a array of objects saved in state which I refresh periodically. Based on this array I create a table in which I use the sematic-ui-react popup like so:

```
 <Table.Cell>
   <Popup
     trigger={<Moment fromNow>{action.started}</Moment>}
     content='some content'
     size='tiny'
   />
 </Table.Cell>
```

This basically works fine until I hover (and therefore trigger) the popup. With the next reload and rerender the Moment element stops working and just showing the time instead of the ago time

-> a day ago

becomes

-> January 17, 2019 12:37

I am relatively new to react and wonder if I miss something important?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `toNow` instead, since it's a date in the past?

Also, it might be possible that the `<Moment />` component is rendering before `action.started` is set. You might want to change that line to:

`trigger={action.started && <Moment fromNow>{action.started}</Moment>}`

to ensure that `action.started` has a value before Moment's render